# Can "git fetch" be told not to use "git upload-pack" for local repositories?

Tags: git, git-fetch

When using `git fetch` to fetch refs from one (very large) repository to another one on the local machine, `git upload-pack` takes a very long time to create pack files.  In the local case there's not such a need to minimize the amount of data transported, and I don't care about disk space lost by losing delta compression, so ideally I'd prefer for the missing objects to be copied rather than packed and then imported.  Is there any way to tell `git fetch` to just copy the missing objects when using the local transport?

Or, more generally, is there a way to suppress the generation of pack files globally?  Really I just want to use git as a versioned filesystem that doesn't use up extra space for identical files - packing and repacking seems to be the time-consuming step that makes this awkward.

Incidentally, I've spent some time trying to optimize config options so that repacking doesn't take so long (nor start thrashing) so I don't think the answer is "use these config options and packing will happen much faster" - however, perhaps I've got that all wrong, so just to be clear, the config options that I'm typically using (on a maching with 2 GiB of RAM) are:

```
core.deltacachesize=1
core.packedgitwindowsize=16m
core.packedgitlimit=128m
pack.packsizelimit=512m
pack.windowmemory=200m
pack.deltacachesize=200m
pack.window=4
pack.compression=3
pack.threads=0
gc.auto=0
gc.pruneexpire=never
receive.autogc=false
```

Comment: afaik, git uses hardlinks when cloning a repository locally. i don't know about fetching though

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use **alternates** (*alternate object storage*) mechanism; this would allow sharing object database with other *local* repository, and then not having to pack them.

To set up this, use '[git clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)' using either `--shared` option if cloning from local repository, or `--reference <repository>` if cloning from remote repository but when you have similar repository locally, or just edit [`.git/objects/info/alternates` file](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrepository-layout.html).

Comment: Jakub: thanks for the answer - I've used alternates before for this, but in the current case I do want to merge the object databases so that I have a standalone repository.  As I understand it, making a repository with alternates into a standalone repository would still involve `git repack` and so the length packing procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I have a repository that plain old `git clone` will not clone:

```
$ git clone $url
Cloning into foo...
remote: Counting objects: 6142, done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9839/6058)   
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Although it's concealed by the progress text which it overwrite, the failing error message is `error: pack-objects died of signal 9`.

I was able to prevent the error by disabling packing on the client side. I did this by issuing a sequence of commands (issued with git 1.7.4.1) that basically do what `git clone` does, but with an extra command to set `pack.depth` to `0` before running `git fetch`.

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
git init
git remote add origin $url
git config pack.depth 0
git fetch origin
git branch --set-upstream origin origin/master
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, especially given that the question is now ancient in S.O. terms :)  I'll try that out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (not tested) setting up a [`http-backend`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html) for your first repo (the one from which you are fetching).

This kind of server has a setting which could be of interest in your case:

```
http.uploadpack
```

> This serves `git fetch-pack` and `git ls-remote` clients.
>   It is enabled by default, but a repository can disable it by setting this configuration item to false.

Comment: Thanks, VonC, but doesn't setting http.uploadpack=false just disable fetching from the smart HTTP transport entirely?  (That's what the test in t556x_common suggests to me, anyway.)  That said, I think the actions of the dumb HTTP transport may be what I want to mimic but as an option for the local transport.  I should at least try to set up a lightweight HTTP server to see whether using the dumb tranport would be a speed improvement...

Comment: @Mark: that may very well disable the smart HTTP transport. But even with a simple local transport, that is worth a try.